# MySQL: Flush Privileges of Single User

Tags: mysql

On Mysql 5.1.72 I created a replication user. Right before running `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` this thought passed my mind what if there are any unapplied privilege updates?

1. How can I flush privileges of a single user?
2. How can I check the
   list of changes about to get applied once `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` is
   processed?
3. If things go wrong is there any way to revert the
   changes?

Comment: "No" to all 3..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer applies to all versions of MySQL up to, *but maybe not including 8.0*.

1. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` syncs the entire set of privileges.  No way to flush just one user's.
2. No way.
3. Run the equivalent opposite action -- `REVOKE` <-> `GRANT`, etc.

A full dump of certain tables in `mysql`:  `user`, `db` and a few others.  This is the 'source of truth' for the current state of all the `GRANTs`.  Editing the tables with `UPDATE` (etc) SQL statements has the equivalent effect to `GRANT/REVOKE/FLUSH`.